# Testing WCF Service which uses IdentityPrincipal

Tags: c#, wcf, unit-testing

I want to write some unit tests for a web service I am creating. Problem is, this service is using the authentication and authorization based on membership and role provider. And methods inside the service use the ServiceSecurityContext.Current.Identity, to access information about the current user.

Now I am not sure how can I test such a service? Can I somehow mock the ServiceSecurityContext? Or maybe I should just create the HostedService in my test project, and run it at test startup? Or maybe I shouldn't test it at all?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend hiding this property behind an interface of your own to enable easy mocking and injecting an instance of this class into your service. This will also enable you to change the mechanism for retrieving the current identity without impacting many code files.

```
public interface IUserProvider 
{
  IIdentity Identity { get; }
}

public class UserProvider : IUserProvider
{
  public IIdentity Identity 
  {
    get { return ServiceSecurityContext.Current.Identity; }
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work, because I use annotions like "[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "MyRole")]" to test if the user has a certain role, and this value is taken from the information stored in the current thread.

Comment: The isolation framework Moles might help here: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/moles/